# A word meaning distant and out of sight

Tags: single-word-requests

Some languages, such as Sinhala, have a three-way split for demonstratives: close, distant within sight, distant out of sight.

We generally have a two-way split: close (*this*, *these*), distant (*that*, *those*).

We also have the rarely used word *yonder* meaning "distant but within sight". Is there a single word or an idiomatic phrase that means "distant and out of sight"? I found *hinter* as in *hinterland*, but that doesn't seem to be an independent word in English.

Comment: 'Afar' or 'afar off' describes something that is towards or beyond the horizon in distance.

Comment: Alternatively, 'beyond the horizon' can be shortened to 'the beyond'.

Comment: I like @NigelJ suggestions of descriptions.  If you were looking for alternatives for "this, these" and "that, those"  .. "others" could be used ... while not precisely limited to distance I think it is a idomatic word reached to.  "This beach is all sand, that beach in the next cove is pebbly, and others on the island are all rock" - it is more about vagueness of location than father location though .. "those further away" .. , while not a word, would clarify distance. 'further' can be used multiple ways.

Comment: @NigelJ - aye aye

Answer (score 1):

**beyond the horizon**  [TFD](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/Beyond+the+Horizon)

> Farther than the possible limit of sight

Answer (score 0):

Out of sight, out of mind

Over the hills and far away

Obscured?  Does not imply distant.

Comment: What happens in Vegas ;)

Comment: OP requests a single word, with a citation to defend your answer.